# scipy.sparse.dia_matrixの使い方

Tags: python, scipy

[マニュアル](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dia_matrix.html) 等で `scipy.sparse.dia_matrix` の使い方を調べると、

```
dia_matrix((data, offsets), shape=(M, N))
where the data[k,:] stores the diagonal entries for diagonal offsets[k]
```

との説明とともに下記のような例が示されています。３行4列のdata配列にoffsetsをどのように作用させると４行4列になるのかよくわかりません。ご教示いただければ幸いです。

```
data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4]]).repeat(3, axis=0)
offsets = np.array([0, -1, 2])
dia_matrix((data, offsets), shape=(4, 4)).toarray()
array([[1, 0, 3, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 4],
       [0, 2, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

「4行4列になる」のは`shape=(4, 4)`としているためです。
※「m行n列にする」には`shape=(m, n)`とします。

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import dia_matrix
data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 20, 30, 40], [100, 200, 300, 400]])
print("data=")
print(data)
offsets = np.array([0, -1, 2])
dm = dia_matrix((data, offsets), shape=(4, 4)).toarray()
print("dm=")
print(dm)
```

結果

```
data=
[[  1   2   3   4]
 [ 10  20  30  40]
 [100 200 300 400]]
dm=
[[  1   0 300   0]
 [ 10   2   0 400]
 [  0  20   3   0]
 [  0   0  30   4]]
```

試しに`shape=(3, 5)`としたときの結果は次のようになります。

```
dm=
[[  1   0 300   0   0]
 [ 10   2   0 400   0]
 [  0  20   3   0   0]]
```